# Does a Flameskull recover its spell slots when it Rejuvenates?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, lost-mine-of-phandelver

I am running Lost Mine of Phandelver and my party just destroyed the Flameskull for the 1st time.

Since it will rejuvenate in 1 hour, my question is: does it recover all spell slots used or not?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour); they're a useful introduction to the site.

Comment: FWIW: Mike Mearls' [tweet](https://www.sageadvice.eu/if-a-flameskull-gets-killed-does-it-also-regain-any-spell-slots/) on this.

Answer (score 16):

> Rejuvenation. If the flameskull is destroyed, **it regains all its hit
>   points** in 1 hour unless holy water is sprinkled on its remains or a
>   dispel magic or remove curse spell is cast on them. (MM 134, emphasis mine)

This trait says nothing about spellcasting, it only states that hit points are restored. So that is the only effect it has. It is still the same skull, so the spells already used up return only next day.

Comment: Why next day? Wouldn't it be after it takes a long rest?

Comment: @Bloodcinder Monster stat blocks list the spells differently than the way player characters use them.

Comment: @Javelin That doesn't effect spell slot recovery. The Flameskull has the Spellcasting feature. It should be long rest, not next day, but I was trying to be polite by asking rhetorically. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80891/how-do-spell-casting-monsters-prepare-and-recover-their-spells

Answer (score -4):

I would say that it does not recover its spells because that usually is taken up by a Long Rest.  I'm not familiar with the module itself, but if it had Warlock traits to it, perhaps then you could recover some spells since the 1 hour restoration would fit into the Short Rest category.

Comment: Hello Winterborne, welcome to the site! Make sure you [take the tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a good introduction to the site.