# Does a reformed Lich come back with all its spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

After being destroyed, a lich reforms in 1d10 days with all its hit points. When it reforms, must it then complete a long rest to recover the spell slots it likely expended to prevent it's initial destruction?

As described in this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97241/does-a-flameskull-recover-its-spell-slots-when-it-rejuvenates), the flameskull only regains its hit points, not expended spells. However, the flameskull in that answer reforms after 1 hour, which is not long enough to complete a long rest.

I've tagged this with 5e, but if there is no information within those books, I would be interested in answers from other editions.

Comment: I misunderstood the title and started trying to look up alignment changes.

Comment: The concept of a "long rest" didn't exist before Fourth edition. Also, in earlier editions, there were multiple kinds of spellcaster, and each had a slightly different method of preparing spells, regaining spell slots, or recharging their power points, and they would retain those different methods upon becoming liches. So, it's a bit tricky to answer this question for earlier editions.

Answer (score 10):

It works the same as any other effect that returns a creature to life (though a lich, being undead, isn't technically living, it's the same concept).  Being dead doesn't count as a long rest, so you would then need to take a long rest before regaining spell slots.  If, as the DM, you want to count the last 8 hours of the 1d10 days the lich spent regenerating as a long rest, you certainly can of course.

Comment: So, fun fact: nowhere does it say in the _Monster Manual_ that monsters need a long rest to recover spell slots. How long until they recover them is always a DM call.

Comment: I support what @TheVagrantDog mentioned. It is the DM's call if the lick[sic] comes back at full power. I'd rule in such a way. After all, it was just rejuvenating in its philactery, never really destroyed or dead.